# NewtonSoft.Json assembly does not match

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-assembly

I made a simple project that uses Json and ReshSharp Portable in a class library.

I always have this exception when I lanuch the app:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

The Newtonsoft.Json is in the library (nuget)and has No dependancy (that nuget says).
For the versions, all is OK, the exception says 6.0.0.0, it is that version that is in the Reference Folder.

This is app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.28.0" newVersion="4.2.28.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This is packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable" version="1.6.3" targetFramework="portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.28" targetFramework="portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.5" targetFramework="portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />
</packages>
```

Thanks in advance to help me

**EDIT:** I launch this Class Library by one console application

This is the new app.config that I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.28.0" newVersion="4.2.28.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.5" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

NewtonSoft.Json infos (on telerikJustDecompile):

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Newtonsoft")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © James Newton-King 2008")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("6.0.5.17707")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Json.NET")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Json.NET Portable")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.0.0.0")]
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Newtonsoft.Json.Dynamic, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100cbd8d53b9d7de30f1f1278f636ec462cf9c254991291e66ebb157a885638a517887633b898ccbcf0d5c5ff7be85a6abe9e765d0ac7cd33c68dac67e7e64530e8222101109f154ab14a941c490ac155cd1d4fcba0fabb49016b4ef28593b015cab5937da31172f03f67d09edda404b88a60023f062ae71d0b2e4438b74cc11dc9")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Newtonsoft.Json.Tests, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100f561df277c6c0b497d629032b410cdcf286e537c054724f7ffa0164345f62b3e642029d7a80cc351918955328c4adc8a048823ef90b0cf38ea7db0d729caf2b633c3babe08b0310198c1081995c19029bc675193744eab9d7345b8a67258ec17d112cebdbbb2a281487dceeafb9d83aa930f32103fbe1d2911425bc5744002c7")]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows=true)]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259", FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Portable Subset")]
```

NewtonSoft.Json properties (in VS):

Runtime version: v4.0.30319
Version: 6.0.0.0

In NuGet Packages, Json.Net is referenced as version 6.0.5

Comment: Is your app a portable app or regular app?

Comment: Also, do you see the dll being referenced from `packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.5\lib\portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10` location? Does it exist under packages?

Comment: @Mrchief : the exception is in a PCL, but launched by a console app

Comment: Ok. What about the location?

Comment: @Mrchief I don't understand your question...one build, the dll is in the same directory than the .pdb and so on

Comment: When you add the NuGet package, it creates a folder for each available target framework that the package supports. I just wanted to ensure that the dll can be located physically under `packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.5\lib\portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10‌​`.

Comment: ah @Mrchief I maybe change the target framework of the PCL after importing nuget package, how Can I make it work correctly? I think this is the problem! I tried to make a folder portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10‌​‌​ with copy/paste the dll but it doesn't work

Comment: Look under `packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.5\lib`. Then select a folder that best suits your needs. I don't have Mono stuff installed on my box so I can't say for sure, but targeting both PCL and .Net4.5, I see a `portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81` folder. And in my packages.config: `<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.5" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80" />`

Comment: @Mrchief: ok, I see some directories under json/lib: portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81 and portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81. I tried to put those folder name on targetFramework on packages.config but it doesn't worked...

Comment: And did you update your references to point to that location as well?

Comment: @Mrchief: in the packages/Json folder, there are portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81, portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81, netcore45, net45, net40, ...(older versions), so I tried every dll and I updated the targerFramework of in the packages.config every time to have the same path+targetFramework. I don't think it helped :-/ What Can I try? Thanks

Comment: Try using [Fusion Log](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/06/02/debugging-load-problems-using-fusion-log.aspx) and see what locations it is searching from.

Answer (score 3):

A common cause of this sort of error is a dependent assembly trying to find an assembly in a version that you do not have. Let's say you use `ProjectX` and `ProjectX` required Json.NET 6, and you only have version 6.0.5. That would cause a problem. You can either install the required version or use `assemblyBinding`.

`assemblyBinding` allows you to serve a version that is different fro the version requested. The requested version is `oldVersion` and the served version is `newVersion`.

Try this:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.5" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

If the numbers in the above snippet don't match, try to tweak them until it does.

Comment: good try but this didn't work, same exception at the same place. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I have again the same exception (they talk of 6.0.0)

Comment: Can you please confirm the version that you have installed?

Comment: The old version is 6.0.0.0 for sure. Now we need to know exactly the version you have installed so we can put this in the `newVersion`.

Comment: I tried <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.5.17707" /> but no effect

Comment: Is it possible to you to just reference the required version? 6.0.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

Great resolved my problem:-)
Instructions:
First find which version of Newtonsoft.Json installed (check in package.config file) and old version should be 0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0 and newVersion = "which you  installed"

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.4" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```